# Replace two text string that assigned to variables with each other in XML document

Tags: xml

I have a test.xml document like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flashget>
    <Downloads>
        <Item1>
            <URL>http://host.com/test.zip</URL>
            <ParentDir>1</ParentDir>
            <Name>test.zip</Name>
            <Referer>http://host.com/myfiles</Referer>
            <SendReferrer>0</SendReferrer>
            <MaxSegments>15</MaxSegments>
            <Attempts>25163</Attempts>
            <URL>http://host2.com/test2.zip</URL>
            <ElapsedTm>1073426633</ElapsedTm>
            <FileDate>0</FileDate>
            <Resumable>1</Resumable>
            <Browser>1766278484</Browser>
            <SaveRedirURL>0</SaveRedirURL>
            <PreserveFileDate>0</PreserveFileDate>
            <ApplySizeRules>0</ApplySizeRules>
```

I need to replace text string that assigned to variables `$L1` with text string that assigned to `$R1` variable inside .xml document.

showing text string that assigned to variables : (text string that assigned to variables changes frequently , that's why I use it )

```
echo 
%L1% http://host.com/test.zip
echo 
%R1% http://download.com/book.zip
```

So new output.xml should be this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <flashget>
        <Downloads>
            <Item1>
                <URL>http://download.com/book.zip</URL>
                <ParentDir>1</ParentDir>
                <Name>test.zip</Name>
                <Referer>http://host.com/myfiles</Referer>
                <SendReferrer>0</SendReferrer>
                <MaxSegments>15</MaxSegments>
                <Attempts>25163</Attempts>
                <URL>http://host2.com/test2.zip</URL>
                <ElapsedTm>1073426633</ElapsedTm>
                <FileDate>0</FileDate>
                <Resumable>1</Resumable>
                <Browser>1766278484</Browser>
                <SaveRedirURL>0</SaveRedirURL>
                <PreserveFileDate>0</PreserveFileDate>
                <ApplySizeRules>0</ApplySizeRules>
```

I am using [XMLSearchAndReplace](https://xmlsearchreplace.codeplex.com/documentation).

**My own code which is not working:**

```
XmlSearchAndReplace.exe /O=en /S=%L1% /R=%R1% /F=d:\test.xml
```

Comment: that's nice. Good luck figuring out the problem. Did you have a question? On the meta-level, what variables? You have no variables in that XML snippet.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code that you have written to try to solve this problem.

Comment: I mean replace the text inside of L1 with the text inside of R1.hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

`/O=en` searches the element name, but you want to search the value, so you need to use `/O=ev`. You can put your variables in a file, and then call it using the following command:

```
XmlSearchAndReplace.exe /O=ev /F=d:\test.xml /P=d:\your_parameter_file.txt
```

In `your_parameter_file.txt`

```
/S="http://host.com/test.zip" /R="http://download.com/book.zip"
```

You can change the URLs in `your_parameter_file.txt` as appropriate.

To run it without the parameter file, call

```
XmlSearchAndReplace.exe /O=ev /S=http://host.com/test.zip /R=http://download.com/book.zip /F=d:\test.xml
```

Comment: thanks a lot but I need to replace text string that assigned to variables L1 with text string that assigned to R1 variable inside xml document. it's not working with XmlSearchAndReplace.exe as I think. Combination of XML.exe & sed.exe will work ?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but I don't understand where you have the variables `L1` and `R1` stored. They can't just appear out of thin air...

Comment: I generated them the line before like this :
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (links.txt) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set L!vidx!=%%A

Comment: If `L1` and `R1` are defined, you should be able to run `XmlSearchAndReplace.exe /O=ev /S=%L1% /R=%R1% /F=d:\test.xml` in your batch file.